# Cannot use GDAL algorithms in processing modeler (QGIS 3.0)

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I am trying to run a fairly complex model in QGIS 3.0, but when I try to use a GDAL algorithm which uses the output of another algorithm as input, I get error messages about an unexpected '(' character in the ogr2ogr command. The command it tries to run is:

```
ogr2ogr "/tmp/processing_8e14b7ffb2794d6985ee9b732c45d59b/a1896a49f4a648ef80fef64fd3679b70/OUTPUT.shp" memory?geometry=LineString&crs=EPSG:4647&field=Klasse:string(1,0)&field=Breite:double(12,11)&field=Bemerkung:string(254,0)&field=offset:double(10,3)&field=layer:string(100,0)&field=path:string(200,0) -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(geometry, 0.5) AS geometry, Klasse,Breite,Bemerkung,offset,layer,path FROM 'None'" -f "ESRI Shapefile"
```

so it seems to be the part where memory comes into play in the command. I don't know if this is a bug in the processing modeler or if it is something that I am doing wrong. I have also tried with a simple input to GDAL "Points along lines" and then output, and this throws errors as well.

My question is - am I doing something wrong with trying to use GDAL algorithms in the Modeler, or is there some way of getting it to accept the input from one of the other algorithms that are being run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in QGIS 3.0/3.0.1. It will be fixed in 3.0.2. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6760